Surjectivity of a bilinear map $A^m\times A^n\to A$ for a polynomial ring $A$
Let $k$ be a field and $A:= k[x_1, \dots, x_d]$.
Question: Suppose $M$ is an $m\times n$ matrix over $A$. If the entries of $M$ generate the unit ideal of $A$, must there exist $a\in A^m, b\in A^n$ such that $aMb = 1$?
The answer to the question is positive if $d \leq 1$, the $d=0$ case by linear algebra and the $d = 1$ case by reducing $M$ into Smith normal form. The answer to the question is also positive if the entries of $M$ are assumed to be homogeneous polynomials or if the ring $A$ is replaced by a local ring, as one of the entries of $M$ will be a unit in this case.
I have looked for counterexamples which involve $2\times 2$ matrices over $A = k[x,y]$, but I don't know of any good methods for solving the resulting Diophantine equations over $A$.

How about something like $\begin{bmatrix}
1 +x & y \
z & x
\end{bmatrix}$?

A counter example can be constructed as follows. Take the curve $f=0$ for some suitable $f\in A=k[x,y]$. Take a nontrivial line bundle $L$ on $f=0$. Then it has a resolution, $ 0\to A^2\to A^2\to L\to 0$. This gives you a $2\times 2$ matrix which one checks is a counter example.

@Mohan, thanks so much! This question has been bothering me on and off for months.
Nate, your matrix gives a counterexample too, but I don't see a direct way to verify it. The best I can do is to not that, for appropriate choice of f, L, your matrix specializes to Mohan's example.
In particular, take $k = \mathbb R, f = x^2 + y^2 - 1, L = (x, y+1)\subseteq k[x,y]$. Then the resolution of $L$ gives rise to the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
y + 1 & -x\
x & y-1
\end{bmatrix}.

Edits: $L$ lives in $k[x,y]/f$, not $k[x,y]$. "not that" should read "note that."
